# Is there anything wrong with messing with the rules of Dreidel?

Tags: minhag, chanuka, mesorah-tradition, games-toys, dreidel

In [this article](http://www.slate.com/articles/life/holidays/2014/12/rules_of_dreidel_the_hannukah_game_is_way_too_slow_let_s_speed_it_up.html) on *Slate*, Ben Blatt calls the [classic rules of Dreidel](http://www.chabad.org/holidays/chanukah/article_cdo/aid/597253/jewish/Dreidel-Instructions.htm) "slow and unfair," citing simulation-based statistical analysis, and proposes his own modified rules to speed up the game.

Given that the rules we have come as a tradition from previous generations, are we required to preserve them, unmodified, and reject reforms such as this one?

Comment: related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Teetotum

Comment: Nice article! []

Comment: There's an old _American Mathematical Monthly_ article called "An Ancient Unfair Game" iirc that proves the game more favorable toward earlier players (so this _Slate_ author reinvented the wheel to some extent). There was a subsequent article (by a different author) called something like "An Ancient Game Made Fair" that suggested specific rule emendations that make the game fair. (Unlike the _Slate_ rules, though, these included turn-taking.)

Comment: עי' חולין דף ז ע"א: אף אני מקום הניחו לי אבותי להתגדר בו מכאן לתלמיד חכם שאמר דבר הלכה שאין מזיחין אותו ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say, "mess away!"

While relatively recent Hassidic sources have ascribed all sorts of significance to the dreidel, if I'm not mistaken the earliest sources simply discuss the practice of gambling on Chanukah. (Chavos Yair, if I'm not mistaken.) Dreidel seems to simply be a form of gambling that rabbis originally tolerated at best, that at some point became part of the American commercial thingamajob that everyone observes as Hanukkah -- and that Hassidic Jews assume must have been an iron-clad practice.

Comment: Gambling on Chanuka far precedes the Chavos Yair. And dreidel precedes (although not by a whole lot) American commercialized Chanukah - the Chasam Sofer felt it was important to spin a dreidel on Chanukah.