# Are the letters on a dreidel supposed to be in any particular order?

Tags: minhag, chanuka, aleph-bet-letters, games-toys, dreidel

This is a little silly, but...

Should the letters on a dreidel be in order? Like, if you turned it right to left, should it go nun - gimel - hey - shin, because of "nes gadol haya sham"? Or are there no rules because it's just a traditional toy and not a ritual object?

Comment: Hey aleck, welcome to Mi Yodeya! Thanks for bringing your question here. My feeling is that it's just a toy, but I don't know for sure. || You might want to consider [registering](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/login) your account, which will [give you access](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/44557/why-should-i-register-my-account) to more of the site's features. I hope to see you around MY! :)

Comment: Related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/50429/is-there-anything-wrong-with-messing-with-the-rules-of-dreidel

Comment: I'm not quite understanding exactly what you're asking. There's no professional dreidel association that mandates a standard dreidel for professional competitions. Are you asking if there's a halacha about how a dreidel should look? I guess I'm asking what you mean by rules. There is definitely a set form that pretty much all dreidel manufacturers follow, but there's no halacha requiring that it be that way

Comment: One of the main sources regarding dreidel (the letters, and being made out of 1 piece of wood) is the הג״ה in the במי יששכר I don't remember offhand if he discusses the order but I will try to post an answer when I am able to look it up

Answer (score 1):

Traditional object not a ritual, and it should go from right to left like any other hebrew.

Answer (score 0):

It also depends on where the dreidel is from, if its an Israeli made one, it will have a pey, a diaspora one will have a shin.

This is because the Israeli ones say:  נס גדול היה פה, Nes Gadol Hayah Poh—"A great miracle happened here"